# python sorting files numeric

Tags: python, sorting, numeric

I am trying to sort a file through python. It's a maths game quiz that records your score. So far I have it sorting by alphabetical only for class 3, as it needs to be split into 3 classes, but I can just add that to the other 2.
But I need to make it sort by highest and lowest score the results are saved like this:

```
name : score
```

Here is my code :

```
def quiz():
import random
import time
import sys

score=0
question=0
menu=int(input("Press 1 To take the Quiz, Press 2 to see all results"))
if menu == 2:
        clas1 = open("Class 1.txt", "r")
        clas2 = open("Class 2.txt", "r")
        clas3 = open("Class 3.txt", "r")
hmm=int(input("What Class do you want 1,2,3:"))
if hmm == 1:
        print (clas1.read())
        time.sleep(5)
elif hmm == 2:
        print (clas2.read())
        time.sleep(5)
elif hmm == 3:
        sort=(input("Do you want it sorted by Alphabetical or by Score Y or N"))
        if sort == ("Y"):
            inputFile = open("Class 3.txt", 'r')
            lineList = inputFile.readlines()
            lineList.sort()
            print('The input in alphabetical order below :')
            for line in  lineList:
                print(line)
        else:
            print (clas3.read())




else:
    name=input("What is your name?")
    clas=input("What Class are you in 1,2,3")
    print ("Alright",name,"Welcome to your maths quiz")

    for question in range (1,11):
        ops=['*','+','-']
        rand=random.randint(1,10)
        rand2=random.randint(1,10)
        operation=random.choice(ops)
        maths = eval(str(rand) + operation + str(rand2))
        print ("Question",question)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print (rand,operation,rand2)
        question=question+1
        d=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
        if d==maths:
            print ("Correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)
    if clas == ('1'):
        f = open('Class 1.txt','a')
        f.write('{} : {}\n'.format(name, score) )
        f.close()
    elif clas == ("2"):
        f = open('Class 2.txt','a')
        f.write('{} : {}\n'.format(name, score) )
        f.close()
    elif clas == ("3"):
        f = open('Class 3.txt','a')
        f.write('{} : {}\n'.format(name, score) )
        f.close()


    if score >=7:
        print ("Well done you got",score,"out of 10")
    else:
        print ("Unlucky you got",score,"out of 10")

    percentage=score/10*100
    print ("You got",percentage,"%")


playagain = 'yes'
while playagain == 'yes': 
    quiz()
    print('Do you want to restart? (yes or no)')
    playagain = input()
```

Comment: Please post an example of your desired/expected output.

Comment: i would like it lets say the file was saved as 
bob : 5
fred : 9
george : 1
i would like it to be sorted fred to george in whoever has the highest scores at the top then lowest at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The [sort](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) function accepts a key function that could be useful here.

```
l = ["foo : 1", "bar : 3", "do : 2"]
l.sort(key=lambda item: int(item.split(":")[1].strip(), reverse=True)
```

Comment: i tried doing this how ever i need to do it directly with the text file itself